# How do I hide "headers already sent" warnings in my PHP script?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written the below script (snipped) that includes the WordPress functions, however it appears one of the plugins is trying to start a session when it has already been started:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

...
?>
```

I get the following in my php errors log:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent in <b>/home/sp32/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-abandon-cart-pro/woocommerce-ac.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent in <b>/home/sp32/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-abandon-cart-pro/woocommerce-ac.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />
```

I'm assuming this is an error in the plugin itself, however I want to prevent these warnings from showing in my log file for my specific script. How would I go about that? Ideally I don't want to hide all warnings, just this one.

Note that is not a duplicate- I am not asking how to fix the issue (because the issue lies in a 3rd party plugin), I am asking how to suppress the warning messages.

Comment: See [How to fix Headers already sent errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) - the woocommerce-ac.php plugin is apparently calling `session_start()`, but you already have some output (even whitespace or a leading linebreak) before that

Comment: Why not remove the offending code?

Comment: Why not remove the offending code? Because this is a paid for plugin that I don't want to mess around with.

Comment: Why are you required to fix someone else's mistake when you paid for it? That's what developer support is for. It's a bad idea to try to mask errors when you ought to get to the root cause.

Comment: @JaredEitnier, I agree it's a bad to mask errors, however the work I am doing has nothing to do with the offending plugin.. it is not my business whether that plugin even works or not, and I am certainly not going to spend time and money chasing up a developer who may not even fix it. I just want to remove the Warnings from my own logs.

Answer (score 2):

There are three options I see here:

1. Fix the offending code. As you have mentioned, this may not be optimal with 3rd party code.
2. Ask for a refund, and replace this plugin with something well written; specifically, something that abides by an accepted coding standard such as PSR-2, or pear.
3. Find where the offending files are included (or offending functions are called and wrap them in calls to change the error reporting level (code below). The downside to this is that your sessions will not work, since the headers have already been sent by the plugin; this prevents a session cookie from being set, making the browser unrecognized by php sessions.

   ```
    $previousErrorLevel = error_reporting();
   error_reporting(\E_ERROR);
    //offending code inclusion or call here
   error_reporting($previousErrorLevel);
   ```